# HttpEntity response getEntity crash

Tags: android, json, response

I have this Activity on my application:
http://pastebin.com/V5nSPqD4

when the application comes to this line:

```
HttpEntity e = response.getEntity();
```

the application breaks down and not respond.

Why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add logcat output ?

Comment: do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: here is the LogCat: http://pastebin.com/wXBXd55F

Comment: Are you sure that's the line? Seems more likely its `JSONArray timeline = new JSONArray(data);`, which should be `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data)`.